Why does typescript give "object is possibly undefined" when object is defined in constructor?
Title says it all. I don't see how this.authService could possibly be undefined after this.authService = new AuthService() in the constructor (or something incredibly close). The base class uses a base class of GenericApiService - why I have to use the const and pass to super before assignment.
export class AuthController extends CrudController<any> {
  authService: AuthService;

  constructor(app: Express) {
    const authService = new AuthService(database.db!);
    super('auth', app, authService);

    this.authService = authService;
  }

  registerUser(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    // TS2532: Object is possibly undefined (definitely this line and definitely authService)
    this.authService.createUser(orgId, req.body)
      .then((doc) => {
        return res.status(201).json(doc);
      })
  }


Are you sure the error is at this line ?

I don't see orgId defined.  Is that inherited?

Can you provide an MWE?

Please [edit] to provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue and only your issue when we paste it into our own IDEs. There should be no pseudocode, typos, undeclared or unimported types or values, missing syntax, etc.

When I tried to replicate your problem, I was not able to. See: https://tsplay.dev/WY132W. With code that doesn't parse, we can't really help more than that other than to say at a glance that this code does not obviously look like it would show that type error at that location.

After tearing the code down to the minimum amount to repro the problem, I found out the issue lied within the "createUser" method of authService, not the controller code I posted above. I thought I had a working function in createUser, but I had not declared a return type. It defaulted to a return type of
Promise<never>

which I'm not familiar with. After declaring a return type of
Promise<User | void>

the issue disappeared.
If someone gets stumped by something similar in the future. Tear down the function you're calling and drastically simplify it - maybe you've got a bad return type.
